# How to throws exception to calling method from cassandra executeAsync() method

Tags: java, multithreading, cassandra, threadpoolexecutor

I have a situation when some cassandra queries may fail and I want to rethrow the exception back to the calling method where I need to perform some task based on the exception occurred, I am not able to achieve it with possible approached available like registering uncaughtExceptionHandler mechanism or by adding a callback handler to the Future object returned by the executeAsync() method of cassandra driver. Please help me out.

**ThreadPoolExcecutor.java-**

```
class ThreadPoolExecutor {

private static ThreadPoolExecutor instance;
ExecutorService executor;

public static synchronized ThreadPoolExecutor getInstance()
{
    if( instance == null )
    {
        instance = new ThreadPoolExecutor();
    }
    return instance;
}

private ThreadPoolExecutor()
{
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(16);
}
```

}

**My Runnable class -**

```
class CassanndraExecCommand implements Runnable {

private final Session session;
private final Statement statement;

public CassanndraExecCommand( Session session, Statement statement )
{
    this.session = session;
    this.statement = statement;
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    ResultSetFuture future = session.executeAsync(statement);
    Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<ResultSet>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess( ResultSet result )
        {
            // do nothing";
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure( Throwable t )
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    });
}
```

}

As you can see above that I am rethrowing the exception in case of failure. Now question is how do I catch this exception in my calling method which is given below -

```
public static void executeSaveorUpdate( Statement statement, String keyspaceName )
{
    ThreadPoolExecutor.getInstance().executor
            .execute(new CassanndraExecCommand(getSession(keyspaceName), statement));
}
```

**Note- cassandra version I am using is 2.2.6**

Comment: .... by setting a try-catch block?

Comment: cassandra executeAsync() does not throws exception until we get Future object and provide onSuccess and onFailure implementation, so not sure where exactly you are pointing to place try catch. Do you  mean try catch in executeSaveorUpdate() ?

Comment: @thedevd, How do you want to handle the exception? What is the aim of catching exception in the calling method

Comment: @mikhali, I have a scenario where multiple cassandra queries need to be run async and if any query gets fail I have a common section where I have to write the stacktrace along with failed queries in some files we say batch file which we want to report to another application.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch exception that has been thrown in a different thread.
So, all you can do is to handle exception using a callback.
That's the price we all pay for async non-blocking calls performance.

Btw, if you need callback for failure only, you can omit "onSuccess":

```
Futures.addCallback(future,
    new MoreFutures.FailureCallback<T>() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        //Do whatever you need with t
        }
    },
    executor);
```

Comment: yes I guess you are correct, that what the async call pays for. By the time children thread throws exception the parent thread already goes too far in its execution so there is no way to catch exception in parent thread. The only thing we can do in child thread is log and handle the exception. Just one more thing to know how it is with the case in sync all.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [ExecutorService.submit(Runnable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) method instead of `execute`. Submit will return `Future<T>` object for you, so you can easily handle exception if any.

```
Future<Void> result = ThreadPoolExecutor.getInstance().executor
        .submit(new CassanndraExecCommand(getSession(keyspaceName), statement));
try {
    result.get();
} (catch ExecutionException e) {
    // e.getCause() will return your root exception
}
```

Hope it helps!

Aside, I think it will be better to implement `Callable` instead of `Runnable` with `CassanndraExecCommand`. This allows you to handle Cassandra response completely (both good and bad) and avoid callbacks.

Comment: Hi Sergey Prokofiev, I am working on multi-threaded enviroment and as far as I know this approach will block the calling thread, thats I dont want. So I guess we will lost the purpose of executing queries asysnchronously.

Comment: @thedevd, in that way, if you don't care about task result and just want to handle exception, you need to create `ThreadFactory`, set `UncaughtExceptionHandler` and pass that factory to your pool.

Comment: @thedevd, I see. So then extend `ThreadFactory` and override `void afterExecute(Runnable, Throwable)`. You can handle exception as you want without blocking main thread.

Comment: I just tried that approach, but the exception is not getting caught in that case even. :(